# What do you call a scrambled omelette?

Tags: eggs, language

I sometimes fry vegetables and chicken, crack a couple of eggs into the pan and stir it all for a while. Serve as is, or with fried rice or noodles.

Does this dish have a common name?

Comment: I call it a buffet omelette, because it's what you usually get from the "omelette" stands at all-you-can-eat buffets.

Comment: Usually I call it a mistake. 

Thank you, thank you I'll be here all week. Please remember to tip your server!

Answer (score 12):

I have heard something similar to what you're describing called a "scramble".   It's usually what I wind up with when I'm out of practice with making omelettes.

Comment: I've heard this quite a lot. I'd say it's common enough to say it's a word for the dish that just hasn't made it into dictionaries yet.

Answer (score 9):

I am quite sure it doesn't have a name in English.

There is the traditional Bulgarian dish mish mash (миш маш), which is an example of what you describe. It never contains chicken, and the classic version prescribes that the vegetables have to be tomatoes and red peppers. But variations are possible, e.g. adding onions and/or feta cheese. It is always scrambled, never cooked to a single-piece omelette. No Bulgarian would even think of classifying it as a type of omelette.

[image: Mish mash]

If a name for mish mash (or a more generic version of it) existed in English, I would expect to find 1) translations in dictionaries listing the English name and 2) mish-mash recipes intended for foreign audience which compare mish-mash to the existing English dish - for example, a recipe for kazanlushki ponichki would probably mention that they are very similar to donuts, but deep-fried. I looked around for such results.

1) wasn't so conclusive a search, because none of the sources I tried offered a translation for mish mash. While the reason could be that the word is too obscure to be listed, I see this as a circumstantial evidence that there is no easy translation. 2) delivered better results - none of the recipes in English I looked into mentioned a similar dish with a known English name. Some insisted that there are similar dish in the Mediterranean region, but did not name them.

Third, there was a hit of a tourist site which stated

```
Q20: What is Mish-Mash? (vegetarian meal)
A20: It is type of omelette.
```

I think that if there had been a better word than "a type of omelette", they would have used it.

So I conclude that the English language, rich as it is, again lacks the name for a dish not usually prepared in English speaking countries :)

As a side note, try adding some (good quality!) feta cheese to your mish mash. It makes a very good combination.

Comment: Thanks for an extensive argument that there's no word for it! I'll wait a bit and see just to make sure that no-one knows a word for it.

Comment: @Tim: Funny that you posted that comment a few hours *after* baka's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A 'Chinese-style' omelette of this nature is known as *fu yung*. This is usually a more coherent, one-piece omelette than scrambled eggs, however; perhaps 'scrambled fu yung' would work?

Comment: Maybe; my dish is definitely not coherent.

Answer (score 0):

I've always called it a western omelet.  Typically red bell peppers and onions figure prominently.

Comment: It seems like a Western omelette isn't scrambled, at least from Google Images and Wikipedia: "A Denver omelette, also known as a Southwest omelette or Western omelette, is an omelette filled with diced ham, onions, and green bell peppers, though there are many variations on fillings."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds closer to a frittata, could also be called a scramble.  An american omelet is fully cooked and has cheese and toppings in the center and is folded over.  A french omelet is rolled so as to have layers.

Answer (score 0):

**Scromlette**, or "scrambled eggs with stuff in them."

Comment: Is this something you've made up yourself or do you have some reference for it?

Comment: Been calling them that for 30 years or more. Never felt the need for a "reference." The web seems to indicate that it's not just me. http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g33377-d1410171-r153380542-McGill_s-Crested_Butte_Colorado.html It even has a hashtag (and that sure isn't me, as I don't twit.)